# Trying to flash a K64F, CPU Could Not Be Halted

Tags: c, microcontroller, cortex-m, jtag, segger-jlink

I am trying to program a Cortex M4 that was placed on a custom board.  The processor is the MK64FN1M0VLL12.  I wrote the code using the FRDM-K64F dev board, which uses OpenSDA to load the bin via USB. The code was written in mbed, which as far as I know doesn’t have any support for loading the program to the processor.   For the production board, I was planning on loading the program via a J-Link programmer, since I didn’t include the OpenSDA interface.

Using the J-Link Commander tool, I’ve found that I have to hold the reset button down on the board in order to get any sort of response.  When I don’t hold down reset, I get the follow: 
[image]

When I do hold down reset, I get:
[image]

When I try to load the bin, I get messages about the CPU not halting.  I get this whether I’m still holding down reset or not:
[image]

The O.K. message is a little misleading.  I tried uploading a program with just a blinking LED, but the LED isn’t blinking.

I’m not sure where to go from here.  Several days of Googling hasn’t led me anywhere fruitful.

Comment: Probably you have some kind of hardware or configuration problem. But it would be nearly impossible to diagnose it here.

Comment: What kind of software is running in it ? Can you try to program it with a very simple software and to reprogram it without to hold the reset button ? There are some power states where the debug interface is not available until you reset the uC.

Comment: 1. please describe your hardware. what lines connected to debugger?

Comment: 2. Try J-Flash tool, it has a friendly GUI. For example, in command-line J-Link utility, for writing data to flash, you should repeat sequences like in-application-programming: write your data to RAM, and then write command to specific registers in flash controller (see "Flash Memory Module" section in Freescale Reference Manual).